# Vuetify Labs: using slots for icons in VDataTable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I want to render an icon in a column of a VDataTable. Did anyone figure out, if it is already possible to use slots for VDataTable in the latest Lab release of Vuetify3.

With Vuetify Version 2.x it could be done like that:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="tableData"
    :items-per-page="10"
  >
    <template #[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
      <v-icon
        icon="$magnifier"
        style="color: #0692bc"
        class="inline cursor-pointer mr-4"
        @click="action(item)"
      />
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    tableData: [
      {
        test_data: 123,
      },
    ],
    headers: [
      {
        title: 'Funktion',
        value: 'actions',
        sortable: false,
      },
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    action(item) {
      console.log(item.test_data);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

That results in an empty column (no Errors, Warnings as its not ready for production yet).

**EDIT:**
Just solved it, it is now `key` instead of `value` in the header objects. So the headers should be:

```
headers: [
  {
    title: 'Funktion',
    key: 'actions',
    sortable: false,
  },
],
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible according to the [documentation](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/#crud-actions). It can be done like this-

```
<template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
  <v-icon
    icon="$magnifier"
    style="color: #0692bc"
    class="inline cursor-pointer mr-4"
    @click="action(item)"
  />
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn't realize that there is already documentation. Thats basically how i implemented it, with no icon showing up.

Comment: Can you check, is your `$magnifier` value correct?